# Neo4j - How to separately manage schema and data transactions?

Tags: neo4j

Does this mean we can not call some thing like this via Java API?
I get error - "Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Cannot perform schema updates in a transaction that has performed data updates."
This happens when I call schema update from a procedure call via neo4j console.

```java
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    String query = "CREATE INDEX ON :" + lbl + "(" + name + ")";
    db.execute(query);
    tx.success();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher query calling the procedure is already executed in a transaction, and there are no nested transactions in Neo4j: when you call `db.beginTx()`, you're getting the existing transaction, and it's not actually necessary unless you need the `Transaction` object (e.g. to create locks).

Anyway, even though it's not explicitly documented, it's apparently not possible to manipulate the schema from Neo4j procedures. You could say that it fails the use case of

> To provide access to functionality that is not available in Cypher, such as manual indexes and schema introspection.

I created a test procedure similar to yours:

```java
public class IndexProcedure {
    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Procedure
    @PerformsWrites
    public void index(@Name("label") String label, @Name("property") String property) {
        db.schema().indexFor(Label.label(label)).on(property).create();
    }
}
```

and ran it from the shell in the simplest Cypher query:

```
CALL my.package.index('Node', 'name');
```

Without the `@PerformsWrite` annotation, I get the following (expected) exception:

> WARNING: Failed to invoke procedure `my.package.index`: Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.security.AuthorizationViolationException: Schema operations are not allowed for `READ` transactions.

With the annotation, I get the same exception as you:

> WARNING: Failed to invoke procedure `my.package.index`: Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Cannot perform schema updates in a transaction that has performed data updates.

I guess the rationale is that setting up the schema is mostly a one-time operation that doesn't really need a procedure: if you're going to execute some Cypher query to call the procedure, you might as well run the script which creates the constraints and indices.

There could also be technical constraints: index creation is asynchronous and probably doesn't participate in the transaction (can you rollback the creation of an index?).

Or maybe it's just a bug? We should get someone from Neo to confirm.

---

**Update:** it will supposedly be fixed in Neo4j 3.1 when it's released, per a discussion on SlackHQ.

Comment: the first statement in the beginTx() is to create Constraints followed by Indexes and then followed by creating Nodes all in it's own transaction.... I never update any data......Please not, the first thing I do   my procedure is fetch Constraints (label & property) information from json file and then make a query string...and call execution/run method...thats all I am doing............. I am not updating any data before the Constraints call

Comment: Just want to understand what do you mean by update the data? Does it mean Neo4j DB data update or any utility operation? If you saying I even tried to run only execute constraints command...that's it....I get the same exception.

Comment: The procedure is invoked by a Cypher query. Is there anything in the query besides `CALL my.procedure()`?

Comment: I've updated my answer after finally trying it myself.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts. I know how much efforts it requires....                              However, The procedure call from with in eclipse creates both Constraints and indexes. This only happens when is a plugin. Hence, it could be a bug. I don't know how to raise as bug to Neo4j.